# Download chrome driver 117

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, curl, selenium-chromedriver

I need to download chrome version 117.0.5846.0 from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json

I know I can use "curl" command to download this, but not sure how to download it from a json document URL.

This is for Windows 64 machine.
Recently my chrome got updated to this version and since then I am unable to run selenium tests from Pycharm IDE and getting the following error.

*selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114*

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some time ago I used **selenium**, and encountered the same problem.
I advise you instead to download the .exe version of *ChromeDriver*.

- Here is the **download** link for **ChromeDriver**: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- Alternatively, check out this site that might help you: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Comment: I tried the .exe version, but I am still having the same issue. It says "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114". I usually store the chromedriver.exe under "C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39". Whenever our company's chrome version is upgraded, I store the corresponding chromedriver.exe there. But for ver 117 I am unable to find the chromedriver. All I see is ver 118 and above.

Comment: I wrote a small python script to extract the URL from JSON doc and then used curl to pull the chromedriver exe.

Answer (score 0):

To install **ChromeDriver** 117 and above for **Selenium**,
you have to use this link:

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/.

Because **ChromeDriver** has 2 links:

1. < **114** https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
2. **117** and more https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

I think it's this

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered and resolved a similar issue a few hours ago, facing compatibility concerns with Chrome version 114.

First of all, it's crucial to note that the encountered issue is not an error but rather a version mismatch.

The root of this issue lies in the fact that the latest version of chromedriver available at this link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE is version 114. Subsequently, the Chrome team (or someone else) altered the update mechanism, resulting in a static version number. Consequently, your automation script consistently downloads chromedriver version 114.

Starting from chromedriver version 115 and onwards, it supports the Chrome version associated with your browser. For instance, if you are using Chrome version 119.xx.x, you should download chromedriver version 119.

To address this issue, you have two viable options:

- Downgrade your Chrome version: This involves using a Chrome version
  that is 114 or lower, ensuring compatibility with the downloaded
  chromedriver.
- Update your automation script: If you are currently downloading the
  latest stable release (e.g., 119.xx.x) using a link like
  https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable,
  consider adjusting it to download the corresponding chromedriver
  version (119.xx.x). This page provides stable, beta, and alpha
  versions of both Chrome and chromedriver for various operating
  systems.

Once you download and install the chromedriver corresponding to your Chrome version, your automation script should resume working seamlessly.

**TLDR**: The link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE consistently provides chromedriver version 114.0, which does not update. As a result, older automation scripts using this version face compatibility issues with the increasing versions of Chrome. To resolve this, either downgrade your Chrome version or update your automation script to download the appropriate chromedriver version. Additional assistance can be found at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection.

Hope it helps!